# Disable options in a child's drop down if its parent drop downs has those options using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck on a requirement wherein I will be having two select dropdowns. First drop down shows the options fetched from a DB that a user has selected. Second drop down has the options which will be fetched from an API service. Basically, a service will return all the values from some master table, assume it returns 10 options and **what I need to do is, if the first drop down has 3 options fetched from DB, then the second drop down should show all the 10 options except that the 3 options of first drop down as disabled**
for eg.
 the first drop down from db looks like

```
<select>
            <option value="" selected="" style="display:none;">Select One 
              </option>
            <option value="one">One</option>
            <option value="two">Two</option>
            <option value="three">Three</option>
        </select>
```

and the second drop down (which fetches data from a service)

```
 <select>
        <option value="" selected="" style="display:none;">Select One 
          </option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
        <option value="four">Four</option>
        <option value="five">Five</option>
        <option value="six">Six</option>
        <option value="seven">Seven</option>
        <option value="Eight">Eight</option>
        <option value="Nine">Nine</option>
        <option value="Ten">Ten</option>
    </select>
```

Now, I should show **One,Two,Three** as disabled and rest as selectable in the second drop down. These two drop downs will be on the same page separated by an hr tag

Im not so strong in Jquery and not able to proceed further on this. Any leads on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where does this "requirement" come from? Is this a school project? My advice is to ask whoever gave you this requirement for assistance with getting started. SO is not a free code writing service, and questions that contain no attempt to solve the problem often are very poorly received. Besides that, you might want to start with writing some simpler programs with JQuery, just to get the hang of things.